# C++ string of "1" does not match "1" (tried regex and boolean '==')

Tags: c++, regex, string

see gif (Visual Studio debugger showing variables): 
http://www.elanhickler.com/transfer/regex_does_not_match.gif

```
bool stob(string s) {
    regex e("1");
    bool b1 = (s == "1"); // false
    bool b2 = (string(s) == "1"); // false
    bool does_it_match1 = regex_match("1", e); // true
    bool does_it_match2 = regex_match(string(s), e); // false
    bool does_it_match3 = regex_match(string("1"), e); // true
    return does_it_match1;
}
```

Why is it not matching?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Llzk.png]
the image shows that the input of s is "1", more specifically characters of `49("1")` and `0("\0")`

ideone: https://ideone.com/b8luZF (this this demosntrates the problem, figured it out thanks to answers below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex e("1");
    string s = "1,";
    s.back() = '\0';

    cout << regex_match("1", e) << endl;
    cout << regex_match(s, e) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the string `s` with quotes around it, e.g. `std::cout << "s = \"" << s << "\"\n";` This way you will easily see what it is, and if it contains any leading/trailing white-space.

Comment: just added a picture.  is it maybe the null termination?

Comment: Your results are consistent with `s` not actually containing `1`. To improve your question, post a MCVE that includes the value being passed to the function.

Comment: Well the debugger do say that the size of `s` is *two* characters. It should not do that unless you manually set the size to two. And no, the size should not include the terminator. Can you please show us how you initialize `s`? How do you call the function? Can you perhaps try and  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg working on it

Comment: So what _is_ the input? Are we supposed to just guess?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Please VTC as such when suggesting an MCVE. The mechanism is there for a reason. Thanks.

Comment: On an unrelated note, that regular expression should probably be `"^(TRUE|T|YES|Y|1)$"` or it would match e.g. `"foo true bar"` as well.

Comment: thanks @JoachimPileborg  also... sorry... what is VTC?

Comment: I'm guessing @LightnessRacesinOrbit meant "Vote To Close".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C-strings, which start where the pointer points and end right before the first 0-byte, `std::string`s can actually *contain* 0-bytes. And that seems to be exactly the case with your string. According to your debugger, the string contains two characters, the first of which is '1' and the second is '\0'.

So you're comparing a 2-character string to a 1-character string and the result is therefore false.

Comment: when you say string a="1", it saves it as 1\0 in memory anyway?

Comment: @GRC: No. (Actually yes per implementation details, but that's irrelevant here.)​​​​​​ So the debugger indicates that that is _not_ what the OP is providing to the function. Yet another reason why we **require** they provide a proper testcase. It should be obvious that "I just trust what I'm passing to the function, therefore so must you" is insufficient when they are the one who doesn't understand the problem!!

Comment: I just did `if (s.back() == '\0') s.pop_back();` and it solved the problem... but is this dangerous?

Comment: @ElanHickler: It's not "dangerous" but it indicates a mistake/error/problem in the calling scope that you should fix at source.

Comment: I think I found the problem. In another function I am doing `descriptions.back() = '\0'; values.back() = '\0';` In other words I am adding a null termination to a string that will eventually find its way to my stob function. I did this to solve a different problem. Guess I need to solve it a different way.

Comment: @GRC Yes, the char-array that `a` contains when you do `string a = "1";` will (likely) be '1', followed by '\0'. But `a`'s size will be 1 and consequently `a[1]` would be out of bounds (and thus invoke UB) and `a.at(1)` would be guaranteed to throw an exception. However what the OP's debugger shows is that the size is 2 and that `a[1]` (or `a.at(1)`) is `'\0'`. So that's what makes the OP's string different from your `a`.

Comment: @ElanHickler If you want to clear a string, [there is a function for that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear), or you could just assign the empty string `""` to it.

Comment: I was trying to convert string to char *, and said function needs size of char *. When I did `&s[0]` and `s.size()` it removed the last char in the string at the output of said function, so my solution was to "end the string early but keep the size" `s.back = '\0'`. But now I am just doing `s.size()+1` to get the right output. Edit: Actually I just realized I can let the function remove the last character and everything is fine. (The last character is a comma, this is a CSV type function, I have no control over it.)

Comment: @ElanHickler use the `c_str()` member function to produce a null-terminated string

Comment: @M.M const char * is not compatible with char *

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing it up, I thought that C++ carried '\0' from C in all circumstances, found that C++ str::string is more like java in some cases, handled by its size not by termination character.